# Reading a numpy array from a text file returns 'nan'

Tags: python, numpy

I am studying from the book "Building Machine Learning Systems" by Cohelo and Ricker.

On page 20 we have to read in the data from a text file:

```
data = sp.genfromtxt("c:\web_traffic.tsv", delimiter="\"t")
```

This is what is being returned:

```
print(data[:10])
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

I've done all the previous contiguous steps, made sure the file path was correct and imported EVERYTHING. 
But strangely, it worked earlier.
Am I failing to import a module or function?

Comment: How many `"`are there in the delimiter?

Comment: If you don't show us the text file (or a sample of it), no one can tell you for sure what's wrong. But it does seem pretty unlikely that someone would use a double-quote followed by a tab as a delimiter…

Answer (score 0):

The routine `np.loadtxt` will load tab-delimited files out of the box and include the `nan` properly.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("c:\web_traffic.tsv")
```

in this case, `data` will have the shape of your file: the first dimension is the number of lines and the second the number of columns.

It is not `sp.genfromtxt` but it is a really powerful alternative.

Comment: Actually, you should just change `delimiter="\"t"` to `delimiter="\t"`